# Is this a valid C command/instruction?

Tags: c, syntax

I am looking over some code someone else did and I see this:

```
            if (numDetects == 0) {

                Table[Index].minF = 

            Table[Index].maxF = F;

            }
```

The Table[Index].minF = blank does not make any sense to me.  I've never seen this in my life.  BUT the code does compile and run, so could someone explain to me if this is possible or not to just have a equal sign left hanging there? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; C doesn't care about the white space between the first line and the second, so it sees it as

```
Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF = F;
```

It's syntactically equivalent to

```
Table[Index].minF = (Table[Index].maxF = F);
```

since the assignment operator `=` not only assigns the left-hand side to the right-hand side, but also returns the value that was assigned. In this case, that return value is then in turn assigned to the outer left-hand side.

Comment: That takes me back. A bug in one of the early PC compilers interpreted assignment inside ( ) as a test, so would return true - because the assignment happened! - so setting minF to 1

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is the same as:

```
Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF = F;
```

The assignment operator (=) can be chained just like any other operator. It is evaluated from right to left, and each evaluation returns the value that was assigned. So this is equivalent to the following two statements.

```
Table[Index].maxF = F;
Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF;
```

Answer (score 2):

White space isn't important. The line really reads

```
Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF = F;
```

Which is equivalent to

```
int a;
int b;

a = b = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to:

```
Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF = F;
```

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is ignored and its all evaluated as...

`Table[Index].minF = Table[Index].maxF = F;`